# Firefox and Thunderbird will not launch - no known changes leading up to this event

Tags: 15.04, firefox, thunderbird

After months of troublefree operation I started my computer to find that I cannot launch either Firefox or Thunderbird.

```
dad@dad-Extensa-5235:~$ firefox
Could not stat private per-user gnome configuration directory `/home/dad/.gnome2_private/': Not a directory
dad@dad-Extensa-5235:~$ thunderbird

(process:2003): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Could not stat private per-user gnome configuration directory `/home/dad/.gnome2_private/': Not a directory
dad@dad-Extensa-5235:~$
```

Ubuntu 15.04
Memory 3.8 GB
Processor Intel® Celeron(R) CPU 900 @ 2.20GHz
 
OS Type 64-bit
Disk 192.6 GB

The software is up to date so no updates are available. My search has not revealed any answered solutions to this problem. Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Thanks

SW

In response to Paranoid Panda -

dad@dad-Extensa-5235:~$ ls -al /home/dad/.gnome2_private –
ls: cannot access –: No such file or directory
-rw------- 1 dad dad 138 Sep 12  2012 /home/dad/.gnome2_private
dad@dad-Extensa-5235:~$

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of: `ls -al /home/dad/.gnome2_private`